# outlook automation in Blueprism

Tags: outlook, blueprism

I am trying send mails using outlook in BluePrism likewise in UIpath. I am new to Blueprism but I don't find an option as Outlook or Exchange Server. I have serached internet and came across a solution of installing Mapiex but I couldn't find the installable and it does not work with outlook64. So Blue Prism does not have a out of the box solution for outlook automation

Comment: If you need to automate Outlook itself, look into either (a) automating the interface like a traditional application, or (b) finding and utilizing the COM object/DLL for Outlook. It has a [VBA interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/vba-outlook), which you should be able to hook into somehow.

Comment: Thanks! I tried using the first option. But its a tedious task. UIpath it was pretty easy.

Comment: Can't you use excell macro to create/send email for you? BP will only open an excell and fire the macro.

Comment: I am not sure if its works. Mail has many parameters and attachments. Not sure a macro can handle that.

Comment: Creating/Sending an email from excell is very easy, there are many exemples of vba code for that. So you could use robot to launch excell and macro that will create/send an email.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your Blue Prism Installation folder and traverse to

> Blue Prism Automate

There you should be able to find Blue Prism Mapiex. Once you import this to Blue Prism tool, you should be able to use it with ease.

Pull in an Action Stage and select Mapiex, like you would with your objects and then you may utilize the actions that come with it.

Check the

> Input

and

> Output

tabs to ensure that you provide all the required information.

Comment: But as far as I researched. Its with outlook 32 bit version. I have a Outlook 2016 64 bit and can't change it. So did not try that out.

Answer (score 1):

Hey here comes blueprism ver6.3.
And you do not need to install MAPIEX add-ons or some DLL files manually.
Only you need to do is import the Outlook VBO which you can find in Blueprism VBO folder in 6.3 ver.
And it provides a quicker method to manipulate Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit tedious process go first you need to install a file named MAPIEX.msi and then import MAPIEX VBO TO LIBRARY AND then bake some settings andit will be configured for Blueprism sending emails.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MAPIEx will only work with the Outlook mail client as a 32-bit application. 64-bit Outlook is not supported.

Check out Email- POP3/SMTP VBO, if these vbo can do whatever you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Mapiex works only with 32bit outlook client,If you are using Microsoft exchange mail,then you can use EWS Managed API and directly access the server and get emails , just instal API and include required DLLs ,but it requires to do some codings.

Answer (score 0):

The Blue Prism (BP) Tool has an Outlook VBO which you can use. You should be able to import the Outlook VBO into your BP instance.

On occasion depending on your outlook setup, you will need to go into your Outlook Trust settings and turn off security popups to make sure the automation can use your outlook without issues.

The issue with using the MAPiex is that whenever you migrating it through different environments and runtime resources, it is a big pain to set it up and make sure it works every time.

Answer (score 0):

You must import the VBO "MS Outlook Email VBO", this VBO contains an action "Send mail", you fill the inputs "From, To, Body, Subject, CC", and you will be able to send an email,

Answer (score 0):

You can just use 2 options to automate Outlook :

- **Outlook Client** : use the 'MS Outlook VBO' which is shipped with Blue Prism installation. This VBO will let you automate Outlook client (no direct connection to Exchange Server)
- **MAPIEx** : you can use this VBO with the .dll files (dependencies) that will let you to connect to Exchange Server (not your Outlook client). Then you can set which profile to use etc.